# ClassCastException on getParcelableExtra with Custom Object?

Tags: java, android

I have CReated a Custom Class called Player, which implements parcelable so i can pass it through my activities in my android application:

```
public class Player implements Parcelable {

// Perks
public Perk tapUp; // Inc Tap Strength
public Perk minDown; // Dec Tap Decrease
public Perk autoTap; // AutoTap at Fixed rate
public Perk tokUp; // Inc Token Reward
public Perk stoDisc; // Store Discount

// GameMode
public boolean campaign;
public boolean insanity;
public boolean survival;

public Player() {
    this.name = "Steve";
    this.title = "the Granny";
    this.rank = 1;
    this.round = 1;
    this.roundAc = 1;
    this.tokens = 0;
    this.maxTap = 100;
    this.hasTap = 0;
    this.minusTap = 5;
    this.plusTap = 1;
    this.tokenBonus = 0;
    this.tapps = new ArrayList();
    this.tapsPerSec = 0.0;
    this.tapsPerMin = 0.0;
    this.tapsInLife = 0;
    this.playing = false;
    this.secAc = 0;
    this.secT = 0;
    this.minT = 0;
    this.houT = 0;
    this.dayT = 0;
    this.sec = 0;
    this.min = 0;
    this.hou = 0;
    this.day = 0;
    this.tapUp = new Perk();
    this.minDown = new Perk();
    this.autoTap = new Perk();
    this.tokUp = new Perk();
    this.stoDisc = new Perk();
    this.campaign = false;
    this.insanity = false;
    this.survival = false;
}


public Player(Parcel in) {
    name = in.readString();
    title = in.readString();
    rank = in.readInt();
    round = in.readInt();
    roundAc = in.readInt();
    tokens = in.readInt();
    maxTap = in.readDouble();
    hasTap = in.readDouble();
    minusTap = in.readDouble();
    plusTap = in.readDouble();
    tokenBonus = in.readInt();
    // Tapp Array pass through activity
    tapsPerSec = in.readDouble();
    tapsPerMin = in.readDouble();
    tapsInLife = in.readInt();
    // Playing = false
    secAc = in.readInt();
    secT = in.readInt();
    minT = in.readInt();
    houT = in.readInt();
    dayT = in.readInt();
    sec = in.readInt();
    min = in.readInt();
    hou = in.readInt();
    day = in.readInt();

    // Pass Perk In Activity
    // Boolean Changed IN Activity

}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Perk> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Perk>() {
    public Perk createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Perk(in);
    }

    public Perk[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Perk[size];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeString(title);
    dest.writeInt(rank);
    dest.writeInt(round);
    dest.writeInt(roundAc);
    dest.writeInt(tokens);
    dest.writeDouble(maxTap);
    dest.writeDouble(hasTap);
    dest.writeDouble(minusTap);
    dest.writeDouble(plusTap);
    dest.writeInt(tokenBonus);
    dest.writeDouble(tapsPerSec);
    dest.writeDouble(tapsPerMin);
    dest.writeInt(tapsInLife);
    dest.writeInt(secAc);
    dest.writeInt(secT);
    dest.writeInt(minT);
    dest.writeInt(houT);
    dest.writeInt(dayT);
    dest.writeInt(sec);
    dest.writeInt(min);
    dest.writeInt(hou);
    dest.writeInt(day);
}
}
```

I removed some of the unrelated code. I have two activities, both of which send and receive information to one another:

Activity 1:

```
package com.tap.tapalot;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import perks.Perk;
import player.Player;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Menu extends Activity {
public Player player;
public ArrayList<Double> tapps;
public Perk tapUp;
public Perk minDown;
public Perk autoTap;
public Perk tokUp;
public Perk stoDisc;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    player = new Player();

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        player = (Player) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("player");
        player.tapps = (ArrayList<Double>) getIntent()
                .getSerializableExtra("tapps");
        player.tapUp = (Perk) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("tapUp");
        player.minDown = (Perk) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("minDown");
        player.autoTap = (Perk) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("autoTap");
        player.tokUp = (Perk) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("tokUp");
        player.stoDisc = (Perk) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("stoDisc");
    }

    final TextView plrTokens = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pltokens);
    String tokStr = String.valueOf(player.tokens);
    plrTokens.setText(tokStr);

    final Button camp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.campaign);

    camp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Campaign.class);
            i.putExtra("player", player);
            System.out.println(player.name);
            i.putExtra("tapps", player.tapps);
            i.putExtra("tapUp", player.tapUp);
            i.putExtra("minDown", player.minDown);
            i.putExtra("autoTap", player.autoTap);
            i.putExtra("tokUp", player.tokUp);
            i.putExtra("stoDisc", player.stoDisc);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
}
```

I Also removed so unrelated code from the activities. Here is the receiving activity:

Activity 2:

```
package com.tap.tapalot;



public class Campaign extends Activity {
public Player player;
public Player tempPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    player = new Player();
    tempPlayer = new Player();

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        tempPlayer = getIntent()
                .getParcelableExtra("player");
    }}
}
```

Here is the error im receiving:

```
12-28 10:53:22.804: E/AndroidRuntime(7446): Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: perks.Perk cannot be cast to player.Player
12-28 10:53:22.804: E/AndroidRuntime(7446):     
at com.tap.tapalot.Campaign.onCreate(Campaign.java:35)
```

Perk also implements parcelable, so im not sure if that causes any issues. But i am not receiving Perk as of yet in Activity 2, so im not sure whats going on.

Thank You for your Time :)

Comment: is there any relationship between perk and player class as you try to cast player to as perk? I don't find one.

Comment: The only possible relationship between the two is that Player contains several objects of the type Perk. But that shouldn't cause any issues.

Comment: if you don't have a relationship between them, you can't also cast themselves to each other. Casting can be done with a super class and its subclasses. Super class be an interface or concrete class. Composition can't be regard as a relationship.

Comment: Im not trying to cast them. I dont know where it is casting them. Thats the problem ;)

Comment: player.tapUp = (Perk) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("tapUp");

Comment: But that line is commented out. In Mine, and it still gives me an error

Comment: This line here:    Player pl = getIntent()
     .getParcelableExtra("player");

Comment: do you comment all these lines:
player.tapUp = (Perk) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("tapUp");
        player.minDown = (Perk) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("minDown");
        player.autoTap = (Perk) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("autoTap");
        player.tokUp = (Perk) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("tokUp");
        player.stoDisc = (Perk) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("stoDisc");

Comment: Well. They dont exist in Activity 2. The error occurs when i enter activity 2. SO it shouldnt matter what i have written in Activity A just yet.

Comment: Does the exception avoid now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `Player` isn't a child of `Perk` in your class hierarchy. Casting from type `A` to type `B` only works if `A` and `B` have a direct relationship via subclassing and/or implementation. If you want a more detailed answer, consider posting your `getIntent()` method.

Comment: BUt i dont want them to cast at all. Thats the problem. I dont know why its casting.

Comment: It appears that `getIntent()` returns a `Perk`, while you are expecting it to return a `Player`. Can you post the method's source?

Comment: Yes. I so stupid. I made two Parcelable objects and just copy pasted the code from one to the other, which off course left it to return a perk each time. Thanks so much :)